Friends in war are stealing gold and one of them got killed
I remember a scene where some friends are stealing gold in a war. And when they stole it they start escaping because some army started chasing them, but one of them shot another friend in the head and left him like that. The main actor then goes to him and finishes him and cuts his head off.
After some years the main actor who finished his friend's (or just his fellow's) life goes into a company that is under the name of the guy who shot him. Then he goes in his office and gives him a bag containing the head of the victim (fellow). Then this guy who shot first is scared and asks the main actor if he wants the gold they stole. After that I can't remember what happened. I can't remember the actors.
Additional details:

It was an American production in English
I watched it in 2009 or 2010
It was in color


Welcome to M&TV. Please add anything that can help identify this movie. Like when did you watch it or which country it belongs to or language of the movie or how characters looked like or any other plot details you remember. Feel free to edit your question and add these details. Also see How to Ask Identify-this-X questions. Thank you.

When did you watch it? Was it an American production? Color or b/w? Was it in english?

It was American production,in english and i watched it in 2009 or 2010,it was in color

Sorry, why are we putting things on hold now instead of improving them when the OP has clearly offered more details? (Thanks for those, Ferid)

I second what Walt asking. I got some comments deleted on a post on hold, with the name a the movie seeked in it. So I edited the original question  adding more details (as required) even if the few details were already enough to find the movie. Nothing change, and when a repost comments, they were again deleted.

@M.Polo Well, that's different, actually. You shouldn't change an ID question to fit the answer.

I don't think he meant that he was changing the question to fit the answer, just that he edited it to include more information, as requested.  (Even though he felt the few original details should've been sufficient.)

That's the problem.I can't remember actors

Which "war" are you referring to in this question?

I think it was war in Afganistan,Iraq or something like that
